How to limit the x axis in matplotlib that labeled with date?
I have a chart of programming languages popularity which each element of x axis are labled with date object, I want to limit the max date to 2012 while mean is auto (untouched).
How can I do it?
I tried using plt.xlim(None, 2012) and it took me to 1975.
Edit: I tried passing touple and list also, but no luck.

You need to pass a datetime to xlim.

As explained here, you can set just the max xlim using the right kwarg:
plt.xlim(right=2012)

Of course, the value passed to the right kwarg may need to be a datetime object, rather than just an int equal to the year in question.

so you are basicaly suggesting that I shall pass a date object instead of integer?
